# S3 show buckets last modified

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to list the last modified file in S3 buckets for a report but the report is showing the first modified (ie when the first file was uploaded not the last file).

I'm using this:

```
top_level_folders[folder]['modified'] = obj.last_modified
```

and adding to the report here:

```
report.add_row([folder[1]['name'], folder[1]['objects'], 
str(round(folder[1]['size'],2)), status, folder[1]['modified']])
```

I've tried adding

```
=obj.last_modified, reverse=True but keep getting invalid syntax errors.
```

This is what the report looks like:

[image: Sample Report]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure as to what you're doing when it comes to writing to the report, but the code below will return a list of dictionaries with the name of each bucket and the time the last-modified file was last modified. E.g.,

```py
[
  {
    'Folder': 'bucket_1',
    'Last Modified': '2021-11-30 13:10:32+00:00'
  },
  {
    'Folder': 'bucket_2',
    'Last Modified': '2021-09-27 17:18:27+00:00'
  }
]
```

```py
import datetime

import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         aws_access_key_id="AKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                         aws_secret_access_key="YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY",
                         region_name="eu-west-2"
                         )


def find_last_modified_file_in_bucket(bucket_name: str) -> datetime:
    last_modified = []
    for bucket_object in s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)["Contents"]:
        last_modified.append(bucket_object["LastModified"])

    return max(last_modified)


def fetch_last_modified() -> [{}]:
    last_modified_file_by_bucket: list[{}] = []
    for bucket_name in list(map(lambda bucket: bucket["Name"], s3_client.list_buckets()["Buckets"])):
        latest_time_of_last_modified_file: datetime = find_last_modified_file_in_bucket(bucket_name)
        last_modified_file_by_bucket.append(
            {
                "Folder": bucket_name,
                "Last Modified": str(latest_time_of_last_modified_file)
            }
        )

    return last_modified_file_by_bucket
```

Without the source code or knowledge of the type of `folder`, I can't say with certainty how you would use the above code to update the folder, but it will likely come down to iterating over the `dict` returned by `fetch_last_modified()`. E.g.,

```py
def update_report(report: Report, folder_with_last_modified: dict):
    for folder in folder_with_last_modified:
        report.add_row(folder['Folder'], folder['Last Modified'])


folder_with_last_modified = fetch_last_modified()
update_report(report, folder_with_last_modified)
```

Comment: Thanks Blair, I've added a screenshot of the report which might explain better what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So "Folder" is bucket name and "Last Modified" is the time the time the last-modified file in that bucket was last modified?

Comment: Yes exactly but as you can see it's showing me the first modified file in the bucket, not the last.

Comment: Updated my answer to match the column headers on your spreadsheet, but I can't give a complete answer without knowing the origins of `folder`.